# Panic when unwrapping HashMap with None value

Tags: rust

```rust
fn pair_finder(pairs_length: u64) {
    let mut path: HashMap<u64, u64> = HashMap::new();

        for i in 0..pairs_length {
            if (metadata.token0 == pair_metadata.token0)
                || (metadata.token0 == pair_metadata.token1)
                || (i == *path.get(&current_depth).unwrap())
            {
                continue;
            }
    }
}
```

I have a function which includes the above block. Path is a `HashMap` where first `u64` is ID of path and second `u64` is pair ID. `current_depth` used is the part of loop where it increases after something new to path is added.

However it panicked. It is because I used the `i == *path.get(&current_depth).unwrap()` in the if block. And `HashMap`is empty at `current_depth` and it got a `None` value. Are there any way to prevent panic on `None` and consider that block of if as `false`?

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value', src/main.rs:69:52
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Option<T>` [implements `Eq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#impl-Eq) whenever `T` implements `Eq`. This means that you can directly compare variants of the `Option` type, like this:

```rust
assert!(Some(1) == Some(1));
assert!(None::<i32> == None);
assert!(Some(1) != Some(2));
assert!(Some(1) != None);
```

So instead of writing this, which panics if `maybe_v` is the `None` variant:

```rust
maybe_v.unwrap() == a
```

You could write this, which just evaluates to `false` if `maybe_v` is the `None` variant:

```rust
maybe_v == Some(a)
```

So in your case, you can write:

```rust
fn pair_finder(pairs_length: u64) {
    let mut path: HashMap<u64, u64> = HashMap::new();

        for i in 0..pairs_length {
            if (metadata.token0 == pair_metadata.token0)
                || (metadata.token0 == pair_metadata.token1)
                || (Some(&i) == path.get(&current_depth))
            {
                continue;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed that seems like the best option. A possible alternative is to use `filter` e.g. `path.get(&current_depth).filter(|it| **it == i).is_some()` (or something along those lines, it may